# Add multi project itself as a dependency in another project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, multi-project

After a lot of searching, it was the last option to raise it here! In eclipse, I am designing such project structure using Gradle, as shown below...

```
Algorithms              //Parent Project
    -SubModuleCore      //Child Project for common utilities & dependencies
        -build.gradle
    -SubModuleOne       //Child project for any operation
        -build.gradle   //Added 'SubModuleCore' as a dependency like compile project(':SubModuleCore')
    -SubModuleTwo       //Child project for another operation
        -build.gradle   //Added 'SubModuleCore' as a dependency like compile project(':SubModuleCore')
    -build.gradle
    -settings.gradle

Services                //Stand-Alone project
    -build.gradle       //Here I want to add 'Algorithms' as a single dependency
    -settings.gradle
```

Project structures are same in eclipse work-space as shown above. I am able to generate individual **.jar** of *Algorithms* project. So the problem is I want to add this *Algorithms* project as a single dependency in project *Services* like `compile project(':Algorithms')`. But eclipse just saying 'shut-up!'. I don't want to publish it somewhere like maven central / jitpack etc. instead I want to do it locally. I'm trying this way...

**Services/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
project.webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':Algorithms')
}
```

**Services/settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'Services'
include 'Algorithms'
project(':Algorithms').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Algorithms')
```

**Algorithms/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = "1.8";
targetCompatibility = "1.8";

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    sourceCompatibility = "1.8";
    targetCompatibility = "1.8";

    buildscript {
       dependencies {
          repositories {
            jcenter()
             mavenCentral()
          }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

}
subprojects.each { subproject -> 
   evaluationDependsOn(subproject.path) 
}
jar.dependsOn subprojects.tasks['classes']
jar {
  baseName = 'algorithms'
  subprojects.each { subproject ->
    from subproject.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
  }
  from files('resources/log4j2.xml')
  from files('resources/application.properties')
}
```

**Algorithms/settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'Algorithms'
include ':SubModuleCore', ':SubModuleOne', ':SubModuleTwo'
```

I tried several solutions from SO, still not succeeded. Somebody please help me, I got stuck badly here. It seems I am very close to this, but don't know what is missing!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [includeBuild](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) feature.

Declare the included build in Services/settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name='Services'

includeBuild '../Algorithms'
```

and then express the dependency using

```
compile "${project.group}:${project.name}"
```

where project group and name the one from the Algorithms project.

Comment: Settings file 'C:\Workspace\Services\settings.gradle' line: 21
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'Services'.
Project with path 'Algorithms' could not be found.
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution

Comment: weird, can you share your project on github?

Comment: My fault! Your solution is 100% working, as expected. Thank you so much. I want one more favor, can you please tell me whether it is a good practice whatever I'm doing or it is not natural? I mean Can I do like this for a web application?

Comment: I think if your 2 projects stays in the same place (e.g. same git repository), it is easier to have a build.gradle at the root. This way, you will not have to do the includeBuild.

also the part where you make the jar task depends on classes is weird, it is best to keep using normal conventions. 
read this for best practices: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html